# SetInterval loop relatively confusing to me

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

HTML

```
<div id="backspace" ng-click="deleteString(''); decrementCursor();">
```

JS

```
<script>
    $scope.deleteString = function() {
        if($scope.cursorPosVal > 0){
            //$scope.name = $scope.name - letter;
            $scope.name = [$scope.name.slice(0, $scope.cursorPosVal - 1) + $scope.name.slice($scope.cursorPosVal)].join('');
            console.log($scope.name);
            setTimeout(function(){ setCaretPosition("inputBox", $scope.cursorPosVal); }, 30);
        } else {
            $scope.cursorPosVal = 1;
        }
    };
</script>
```

I am designing an on screen touchscreen keyboard. This is my backspace button. I am going to make it so that when you click and hold the backspace button, it starts removing characters automatically. I don't know where to begin with creating a setInterval, and I know a setInterval is exactly what I need to use here.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Any errors? I'm still not sure what you exatcly want; please provide further explanation

Comment: So you want to simulate the backspace button with a div ?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not wrong, you want that while you're keeping your button pressed, a function repeats itself.

You're right with setInterval(). However, the way you manage the event is wrong.

Take a look at this fiddle (It's not your code, but a simple example is the best way to understand):

http://jsfiddle.net/daq9atdd/1/

```
$(function(){
    var interval = null;

    $('#myButton').mousedown(function(){
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            console.log('Hello !');
        }, 250);
    });

    $('#myButton').mouseup(function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
```

I start the interval when the button is pressed, store it, and clear it when the button is released.

Comment: Great example, but I am not using jQuery, (can't tbh.)

Comment: If downvoting people could at least help me improve my answer, I'd gladly read their advice : )

Comment: Perhaps someone downvoted because your answer doesn’t directly involve AngularJS. The biggest hurdle is where to put the code—in AngularJS you probably should have this inside a directive, and it’s slightly non-obvious how to write directives. Other than that your answer is valid (have an upvote), except I personally prefer setting timeouts instead of intervals. :)

Comment: @abejdaniels, if you’re using AngularJS you’re already using jQuery, or at least its ‘lite’ version (which supports significant part of jQuery API).  See [``angular.element``](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Answer (score 2):

You’re so sure about `setInterval`.

If browser briefly hangs for whatever reason (say some background task), `setInterval` would go on queueing your backspace calls until it has some CPU time. This means user may see no change and hold backspace longer than needed, and then see a whole bunch of characters suddenly vanish when browser is back to normal.

Thus by setting a timeout after every call you’re making sure user won’t remove more characters than needed. Might be important if the goal is to improve UX.

[**Example implementation with AngularJS directives and setTimeout**](http://jsfiddle.net/daq9atdd/41/)

See also:

- [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)
- [noKid’s fiddle updated with setTimeout in mind](http://jsfiddle.net/daq9atdd/5/)